# How to check if a particular folder or file is shared or not with java program?

Tags: java, windows, file, networking, io

I am working on a java networking project. One of my module need to know if a particular folder or file is shared or not and if shared to whom it is shared. I mean whether it is shared with everyone on network or it is shared with some specific people only as we have option in windows. This also must be an attribute of file but I can't find any way to check this one.

Comment: You'll either need to access the Windows API through JNI or call an external program via Runtime.exec and parse its output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use file's [exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) method to determine if the directory is sharing folder.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress addr;
    addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String hostname = addr.getHostName();

    if (hostname != null) {
        File f = new File("\\\\" + hostname + "\\temp");            
        if (f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("directory temp is shared");
        }           

    }

}
```